# Parsing nullable TJSONObject with Delphi

Tags: json, delphi

I'm using Delphi XE3. I have a JSON stream where an object can be null.  That is, I can receive:

```json
"user":null
```

or

```json
"user":{"userName":"Pep","email":"pep@stackoverflow.com"}
```

I want to discriminate both cases, and I tried with this code:

```
var 
  jUserObject: TJSONObject;

jUserObject := TJSONObject(Get('user').JsonValue);
if (jUserObject.Null) 
then begin
  FUser := nil;
end else begin
  FUser := TUser.Create;
  with FUser, jUserObject do begin
    FEmail := TJSONString(Get('email').JsonValue).Value;
    FUserName := TJSONString(Get('userName').JsonValue).Value;
  end;
end;
```

If I put a breakpoint right in line `if (jUserObject.Null) then begin` and I mouse over `jUserObject.Null` it says `jUserObject.Null = True` if `"user":null` and it says `jUserObject.Null = False` if `"user":{"userName":"Pep","email":"pep@stackoverflow.com"}`

However, if I step into that line with the debugger, jUserObject.Null calls the following XE3 library code:

```
function TJSONAncestor.IsNull: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;
```

So I always get a `False` for my `if` sentence, even if `"user":null`.

I suppose I always have the workaround of catching the exception that is raised when `"user":null` and `Get('email').JsonValue` is executed in order to discriminate if the value is null or not, but that does not seem so elegant.

How is one supposed to detect if an JSON object has a null value in the JSON stream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Get()` returns a `TJSONPair`. When you have `"user":null`, the `TJSONPair.JsonValue` property will return a `TJSONNull` object, not a `TJSONObject` object.  Your code is not accounting for that possibility.  It assumes the `JsonValue` is always a `TJSONObject` and not validating the type-cast.

There are two ways to handle this.

1. `TJSONPair` has its own `Null` property that specifies whether its `JsonValue` is a null value or not:

   ```
   var
     JUser: TJSONPair;
     jUserObject: TJSONObject;

   jUser := Get('user');
   if jUser.Null then begin
     FUser := nil;
   end else begin
     // use the 'as' operator for type validation in
     // case the value is something other than an object...
     jUserObject := jUser.JsonValue as TJSONObject;
     ...
   end;
   ```
2. Use the `is` operator to test the class type of the `JsonValue` before casting it:

   ```
   var
     JUser: TJSONPair;
     jUserObject: TJSONObject;

   jUser := Get('user');
   if jUser.JsonValue is TJSONNull then begin
     FUser := nil;
   end
   else if jUser.JsonValue is TJSONObject then begin
     jUserObject := TJSONObject(jUser.JsonValue);
     ...
   end else begin
     // the value is something other than an object...
   end;
   ```

Comment: That a value is not a JSON object does not imply that it is null. For instance it could be a JSON array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Hence my suggestions to use the `as` and `is` operators to validate the value really is a `TJSONObject` object before accessing it as a `TJSONObject` object. Given the OP's requirement, an array would be an erroneous type.

Comment: If the data is user supplied then erroneous data is quite possible. So I'd prefer to detect that rather than assume non-object is null. But your edit deals with that. Thanks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau how would a user writing c++ use `as` and `is` operators?

Comment: @HappyCoding use C++'s [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) for objects, and the RTL's [`Sysutils::Supports()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Supports) function for interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

You've made the common mistake of confusing JSON objects with Delphi objects. The `TJSONObject` class represents JSON objects only, which are never null because `null` is distinct from `{...}`.  `TJSONObject` is not the ancestor for all JSON values, like your code assumes. `TJSONValue` is.

Don't type-cast your "user" value to `TJSONObject` until you *know* it's an object. Check the `Null` property first, *then* type-cast.